# change url of tab javascript firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, firefox-addon, tabbed

I am trying to change the url of a currently open tab in javascript firefox extension

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's "gbrowser.loadURI()". Try reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) page on MDC about interacting with the global variable gBrowser, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL:Method:loadURI) about the loadURI method.

Answer (score 2):

The mozilla [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) mentioned by TML has sample code for this under "Reusing by other criteria", but it's broken.  The corresponding [talk page](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) says to add this line to fix it:

```
tabbrowser.loadURI(url, tabbrowser.currentURI, "UTF-8");
```

However, if you've already got the tab object (say from calling addTab earlier) then I think it's simpler to do:

```
gBrowser.selectedTab = mytab;
gBrowser.loadURI(myurl);
```

I don't see any way to change the URL of a tab which is NOT selected, but that would be nice - I hate stealing focus.

UPDATE: here's how you do it w/o selecting the tab.  Simple:

```
gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(mytab).loadURI(myurl);
```